# Replace notebooks and pens with Mathematica?

Tags: homework

I use Mathematica for math homework/learning. I'm trying not to use it for solving equations I should be solving by myself to get homework done faster and not learn anything. I think I can (and should) do all math with a computer -> no paper and pen. For achieving this, I've been using Mathematica and Geogebra to visualize geometry problems (Geogebra is a free tool for 2d geometry drawing).

The question:
Solving math problems with Mathematica is easy, but can you use it to learn math? To solve/play around with equations manually? To completely replace notebooks and pens?

Answer (score 1):

What meaning do you put in words "solving problems" and "learning math"? For instance, MMA can give you answer for questions like "what is it equal to" or "is this identity is true", but it won't tell you how did it figured it out. That means that important aspect of learning math such as proving theorems is completely neglected.

Here is [the article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html) by WRI that suggests that there's no intention to explain people how things done by the kernel. I should admit that I'm not a big fan of the main idea of this article, and arguments they provide seem to be silly. From the student point of view, this article means that Mathematica are lacking in some functionality. MMA's algorithms and knowledge base are huge and quite handy, when you need answer on practical questions, even to extent when enormous amount of work have to be done otherwise, either by hand or in some basic programming environment. But the lack of explanation *how* it's done makes it more resembling [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](http://www.mathtable.com/gr/) than some book which will teach you about the meaning of all this math behind simple query from front end to kernel (and you cannot learn calculus from table of integrals as much as you cannot learn language from bare dictionary). There's a lot of situations where answer itself is a huge achievement, but I believe that learning math, especially if we talk about math not in context of practical applications, demands more focus on the definitions, concepts, process of proving, rather then on knowledge of form

$\int e^{-x^a} dx = -\frac{x(x^a)^{-1/a} \Gamma(1/a,x^a)}{a}$

or similar relations of such kind.

There are some more issues like comparing screen environments with pen and paper, but I think it barely play some role. I can imagine one studies math without textbooks, just sitting by the table and considering some abstract objects he is aware of, but I don't think that the oracle of MathKernel of the year 2015 can main instrument to study math.